# Linux remote control over internet

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ssh

I have a ARMv7 mini PC in city A, and a laptop in city B. Both of them are behind router and firewalls, ARMv7 is running Ubuntu 14.04, only user is root, Laptopis running ARch. I want to access the ARM from Laptop.

I used first this in the ARMv7 device :

1. Install OpenSSH

   2. `/etc/init.d/ssh start`
   3. `ufw allow ssh`
   4. `ssh -R 5999:localhost:22 laptopUser@laptop_publicIP`

Then I try to access the ArmV7 device from the laoptop using `ssh localhost -p 5999`.

It ishowever not working. SSH from laptop always times out.

The laptop itself has a Dynamic IP.

Help please.

Comment: Why the downvote? Let em know what my mistake is first ...

Comment: I believe you don't need step (3), `ufw allow ssh`, since you are using tunneling. Step 4 succeeds properly? It gives you a shell on the laptop? If you omit step 4 and try `ssh localhost -p 5999` on the laptop, what does it do? Does it time out again? Or does it immediately say "Connection refused"?

Answer (score 0):

NAT devices and similar stateful firewalls will drop idle TCP connections after a period of time. 
The "router and firewalls" at one end of the connection or the other may be blocking the TCP stream between the ARM device and the laptop after a while because the connection is idle and no actual packages are being exchanged.

On the ARM side (the ssh client), you could try setting the `ServerAliveInterval` and/or `TCPKeepAlive` settings. These will cause the client and server to send occasional packets to each other. Refer to the [ssh_config documentation](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&sektion=5).

Another thing you could try is to run a command within the ssh session from the ARM to the laptop, which outputs some text once in a while:

```
ssh -R 5999:localhost:22 user@laptop 'while true; do sleep 10; date; done'
```

Answer (score -1):

First thing - localhost always points to the machine that you're currently on. So, if you want to make an connection to the remote machine you can't use localhost or any other local addreses :) You neeed to use REMOTE machine IP address.

You'll have to make that arm pc visible from the internet - but that will require an access to the router and firewall in city A.

Or, you can use VPN to connect both machines.

Comment: we can access physically the router in city A. Could you guide me with the settings I have to tinker?

Comment: Don't know the router you have.
Search for "port forward" topic, most regular routers can do this. Just forward port 5999 directly to the ip of the armpc have. Now, you'll have to open this port to the internet. And this finally makes it possible to connect to the machine using your public ip address.

Comment: Of course he can connect through localhost since he is using tuneling.